# How do I add lines for table tr like Tree

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

How can make side lines for every **table tr**, like tree structure?

Also, Nested tables will come in some of **tr**.

Sample code **[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/v75hq1jL/8/)**:

```css
#smsTree {
  margin-top: 30px;
 }
#smsTree tr:not(:last-child) {
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}
#smsTree tr:not(:last-child) + #smsTree tr:not(:first-child) {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 35px;
  z-index: 100;   
  width: 20px;
  height: 100px;  
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
#smsTree tr:first-child:before {
  border-bottom: none;
}

#smsTree tr:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  z-index: 100;   
  width: 20px;
  height: 10%;  
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

#smsTree tr:last-child:before {
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div id="smsTree">


<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
  <tbody>
<tr>
  <td class="standartTreeImage">
    <div class="dhx_bg_img_fix" style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px; width: 18px; background-image: url(&quot;http://localhost:48081/Airtel_BMS_V4/TreeMenu/imgs/csh_red/minus.gif&quot;);">&nbsp;</div>
  </td>
  <td width="16px" style="display: none;">
    <div class="dhx_bg_img_fix" style="background-image: url(&quot;http://localhost:48081/Airtel_BMS_V4/TreeMenu/imgs/csh_red/iconUncheckAll.gif&quot;); width: 18px; height: 18px;">&nbsp;</div>
  </td>
  <td class="standartTreeImage" style="width: 16px;">
    <div class="dhx_bg_img_fix" style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px; width: 16px; height: 16px; background-image: url(&quot;http://localhost:48081/Airtel_BMS_V4/TreeMenu/imgs/csh_red/folderOpen.gif&quot;);">&nbsp;</div>
  </td>
  <td class="dhxTextCell standartTreeRow" nowrap="" style="font-size: 10pt; cursor: pointer;"><span class="standartTreeRow" style="padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px;"><font class="tdSmallBlack" onclick="return anchor_onclick(this)" onmouseover="return link_mouseover(this)" onmouseout="return link_mouseout(this)" style="text-decoration: none;"><strong>1mnthuser [Content Provider]<strong></strong></strong></font></span></td>
</tr>
<tr style="">
  <td> </td>
  <td colspan="3">
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="standartTreeImage">
            <div class="dhx_bg_img_fix" style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px; width: 18px; background-image: url(&quot;http://localhost:48081/Airtel_BMS_V4/TreeMenu/imgs/csh_red/minus.gif&quot;);">&nbsp;</div>
          </td>
          <td width="16px" style="display: none;">
            <div class="dhx_bg_img_fix" style="background-image: url(&quot;http://localhost:48081/Airtel_BMS_V4/TreeMenu/imgs/csh_red/iconUncheckAll.gif&quot;); width: 18px; height: 18px;">&nbsp;</div>
          </td>
          <td class="standartTreeImage" style="width: 16px;">
            <div class="dhx_bg_img_fix" style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px; width: 16px; height: 16px; background-image: url(&quot;http://localhost:48081/Airtel_BMS_V4/TreeMenu/imgs/csh_red/folderOpen.gif&quot;);">&nbsp;</div>
          </td>
          <td class="dhxTextCell standartTreeRow" nowrap="" style="font-size: 10pt; cursor: pointer;"><span class="standartTreeRow" style="padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px;"><font class="tdSmallBlack" onclick="return anchor_onclick(this)" onmouseover="return link_mouseover(this)" onmouseout="return link_mouseout(this)"><strong>BMS_MKT_608[Market Plan]<strong></strong></strong></font></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="">
          <td> </td>
          <td colspan="3">
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td class="standartTreeImage">
                    <div class="dhx_bg_img_fix" style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px; width: 18px; background-image: url(&quot;http://localhost:48081/Airtel_BMS_V4/TreeMenu/imgs/csh_red/blank.gif&quot;);">&nbsp;</div>
                  </td>
                  <td width="16px">
                    <div class="dhx_bg_img_fix" style="background-image: url(&quot;http://localhost:48081/Airtel_BMS_V4/TreeMenu/imgs/csh_red/iconUncheckAll.gif&quot;); width: 18px; height: 18px;">&nbsp;</div>
                  </td>
                  <td class="standartTreeImage" style="width: 16px;">
                    <div class="dhx_bg_img_fix" style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px; width: 16px; height: 16px; background-image: url(&quot;http://localhost:48081/Airtel_BMS_V4/TreeMenu/imgs/csh_red/leaf.gif&quot;);">&nbsp;</div>
                  </td>
                  <td class="dhxTextCell standartTreeRow" nowrap="" style="font-size: 10pt; cursor: pointer;"><span class="standartTreeRow" style="padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px;"><font class="tdSmallBlue" onclick="return anchor_onclick(this)" onmouseover="return link_mouseover(this)" onmouseout="return link_mouseout(this)"><strong>sss<strong></strong></strong></font></span></td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="">
          <td> </td>
          <td colspan="3">
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td class="standartTreeImage">
                    <div class="dhx_bg_img_fix" style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px; width: 18px; background-image: url(&quot;http://localhost:48081/Airtel_BMS_V4/TreeMenu/imgs/csh_red/blank.gif&quot;);">&nbsp;</div>
                  </td>
                  <td width="16px">
                    <div class="dhx_bg_img_fix" style="background-image: url(&quot;http://localhost:48081/Airtel_BMS_V4/TreeMenu/imgs/csh_red/iconUncheckAll.gif&quot;); width: 18px; height: 18px;">&nbsp;</div>
                  </td>
                  <td class="standartTreeImage" style="width: 16px;">
                    <div class="dhx_bg_img_fix" style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px; width: 16px; height: 16px; background-image: url(&quot;http://localhost:48081/Airtel_BMS_V4/TreeMenu/imgs/csh_red/leaf.gif&quot;);">&nbsp;</div>
                  </td>
                  <td class="dhxTextCell standartTreeRow" nowrap="" style="font-size: 10pt; cursor: pointer;"><span class="standartTreeRow" style="padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px;"><font class="tdSmallBlue" onclick="return anchor_onclick(this)" onmouseover="return link_mouseover(this)" onmouseout="return link_mouseout(this)"><strong>sss<strong></strong></strong></font></span></td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </td>
</tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**css:**

```
#smsTree tr:not(:last-child) {
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}

#smsTree tr:first-child:before {
  border-bottom: none;
}

#smsTree tr:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  z-index: 100;   
  width: 20px;
  height: 10%;  
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

#smsTree tr:last-child:before {
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

Please check above fiddle link.

Snap of Design Tree structure:

[image]

Comment: This may help you https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/ypNAe

Answer (score 1):

Normally border does not apply to table border.you need to add border-collapse to table. You can use below code. [specifications](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#borders)

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table tr
{
    border-left:1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: with your code, it won't show like tree, need to connect each tr. Check desing tree

Answer (score 1):

This a simple example that you want to achieve but it is done with a list.  I never saw done with tables. Why? Because you can't control the space between the elements as effective as in a list and also because tables are just to display tabular data.

I edit the code and I added icons with font-awesome to be mo realistic with your design.

I hope helps

```css
ul {
  border-left: 1px dotted;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 12px;
}

li {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 22px;
}

li::before {
  background-color: #fff;
  content: '';
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -12px;
  top: 10px;
  border-top: 1px dotted;
}
ul.tree > li:first-child::before {
  width: 11px;
  height: 10px;
  left: -13px;
  top: 0px;
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted;
}
li:last-child::before {
  width: 11px;
  height: 10px;
  left: -13px;
}

ul.tree>li::after,
ul.tree>li>ul>li::after {
  background-color: red;
  content: '';
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -18px;
  top: 6px;
  z-index: 1;
}

ul.tree>li.open::after,
ul.tree>li>ul>li.open::after {
  background-color: blue;
}

li ul {
  margin: 5px 7px;
}

li i {
  margin-right: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 2px;

}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">



<ul class="tree">
  <li class="open"><i class="fas fa-address-book"></i>06_midh_http_user
    <ul>
      <li class="open"><i class="fas fa-address-book"></i>BMS_MKT_303
        <ul>
          <li><i class="fas fa-address-book"></i>6d</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><i class="fas fa-address-book"></i>BMS_MKT_304</li>
      <li><i class="fas fa-address-book"></i>BMS_MKT_305</li>
      <li><i class="fas fa-address-book"></i>MS_MKT_307</li>
      <li><i class="fas fa-address-book"></i>BMS_MKT_308</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><i class="fas fa-address-book"></i>1111</li>
  <li><i class="fas fa-address-book"></i>1112</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks. But I am using **DHTMLX Tree** , it will generate tree in table format only.

With your CSS the lines are not coming properly

Comment: Check this out:

https://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxTree/samples/01_appearance/07_pro_text.html#

If you just mark Icons and Lines ... I think it is what you want to achieve. If you inspect the code, you will be able to create the same approach